# How to pass hash key value pairs as induvidual arguments?

Tags: ruby

I would like to be able to quickly put the key-value pairs of a hash as arguments into a method.

For example, for the hash:

```
test_hash = {a: "1", b: "2"}
```

I would like to be able to pass it into a method like:

```
method(test_hash.do_something)
```

To achieve:

```
method(a: "1", b: "2")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the double spat (**) on a hash in the method

```rb
  method(**test_hash)
```